# image size listview jquerymobile

Tags: image, listview, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to set a listview like that:

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/lists/lists-thumbnails.html

I dinamicly generate my code

```
$('#calendarPage').live('pagebeforeshow', function(event) {
    $('#calendarPage').live('pageshow', function(event) {
        application.prev = 'menu.html';
        //get the actu
        application.readFile('calendar.json',function(data){
            data = JSON.parse(data);

            var listview = '<ul data-role="listview" class="ui-listview"  id="calendarList" >';
            for(elem in data){
                var date = new Date(data[elem].date);
                var day = date.getDate();
                var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
                var year = date.getYear();
                var hours = date.getHours();
                var min = date.getMinutes();
                var s = date.getSeconds();
                listview += '<li>';
                listview += '<img src="'+application.api+data[elem].img+'" /><a href="actuOne.html?id='+elem+'" ><h3>'+data[elem].title+'</h3><p>'+day+'/'+month+'/'+year+' '+hours+':'+min+':'+s+'</p></a>';
                listview += '</li>';
            }
            listview += '</ul>';
            $('#calendarPage .content').html(listview);
            $('#calendarList').listview();
        });
    });
});
```

Yhe listview is created but the images are not resized

I try adding class="ui-li-thumb" but it works poorly

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the rendered code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an error in your example, **img** tag must be inside a **a** tag, only then it will be resized.

Take a look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/w5bcS/

```
        <ul data-role="listview">
            <li><a href="index.html">
                <img src="http://www.warrenphotographic.co.uk/photography/bigs/05852-Retriever-puppy-yawning-white-background.jpg" title="sample"/>
                <h3>Sample image</h3>
                <p>Sample</p>
            </a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html">
                <img src="http://www.warrenphotographic.co.uk/photography/bigs/05852-Retriever-puppy-yawning-white-background.jpg" title="sample"/>
                <h3>Sample image</h3>
                <p>Sample 2</p>
            </a></li>
        </ul>
```